# Warnings cause stack trace when running Perl code in debugger: can I prevent this?

Tags: perl, debugging

If I have [`warn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) statements in my code, and I run this code normally from the command line, I see the warning message on the console. Similarly if I run this code under Apache my warn message appears in Apache's error log.

If I run the same code under [`perl -d`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html), I see a stack dump every time I execute a warning. The same thing happens when my code passes through an active [`Smart::Comments`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Comments). Can I do anything about this?

Example:

```
  DB<8> 
Highway::eBookGenerator::build(/var/www/highway/app/Highway/eBookGenerator.pm:133):
133:        $self->{opts}->{debug} = '' unless $self->{opts}->{debug};
  DB<8> 
Highway::eBookGenerator::build(/var/www/highway/app/Highway/eBookGenerator.pm:135):
135:        warn "build IS RUNNING UNSTABLE" if $self->{opts}->{runningunstable};
  DB<8> 
build IS RUNNING UNSTABLE at /var/www/highway/app/Highway/eBookGenerator.pm line 135.
 at /var/www/highway/app/Highway/eBookGenerator.pm line 135.
    Highway::eBookGenerator::build('Highway::eBookGenerator=HASH(0xf2da4f0)', 'HASH(0xf1369e8)') called at /var/www/highway/app//Highway/Page/eBookViewer.pm line 2448
    Highway::Page::eBookViewer::create_epub_process('Highway::Page::eBookViewer=HASH(0xf35b038)') called at /var/www/highway/app/_cpan/CGI/Application.pm line 157
    eval {...} called at /var/www/highway/app/_cpan/CGI/Application.pm line 156
    CGI::Application::__get_body('Highway::Page::eBookViewer=HASH(0xf35b038)', 'create_epub_process') called at /var/www/highway/app/_cpan/CGI/Application.pm line 234
    .... yada yada 20 lines of stack dump
    Test::WWW::Mechanize::post_ok('Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI=HASH(0xea5d230)', '/ebooks/create_epub_process', 'HASH(0x159f8d0)') called at t/ebookGenTest.pl line 160
Highway::eBookGenerator::build(/var/www/highway/app/Highway/eBookGenerator.pm:140):
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { };
```

in your main source file should catch and thus suppress any future warnings. Or you can do:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print "$1\n" if $1 };
```

to have a non-intrusive message.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second option gives        
        `Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 1688)[/usr/share/perl/5.14/perl5db.pl:640] line 2.`
I don't mind seeing the warnings/useful messages, it's the stack trace that's unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks, that's going in my `.perldb !`